# Vue computed property undefined when called in another computed property

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, apexcharts

I seem to be stuck trying to call the `return` value from one computed property inside of another computed property.

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
  computed: {
    myTime() {
      var date = new Date(this.myData.doc[9].time);
      return date.toString("YYYY MMM dd hh:mm").substring(0,24);
    },

    myName() {
      return this.$store.getters.findName(this.id)
    },

    series() {

      var series =  [
        {
          name: "TMP",
          data: [28, 29, 33, 36, 32, 32, 33]
        },
        {
          name: "HUM",
          data: [12, 11, 14, 18, 17, 13, 13]
        },
        {
          name: "CO2",
          data: []
        }
      ];

      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        series[2].data.push(((this.myData.doc[i].co2*10)*100)/3000);
      }

      return series;
    },

    myData() {
      return this.$store.state.graphData.find(obj => obj.id == this.id)
    },

    ...mapGetters({
    }),

    ...mapState({
      newSettings: 'newSettings',
      graphDatagraphData'
    }),
  }
```

What I was working on is trying to chart based on this example: https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/line-charts/data-labels/

Because I wanted to to have this data change dynamically with a live feed that gets updated every few seconds I have moved the `series` array that contains the objects to make more lines on the chart from the `data()` function to the `computed:` properties list.

Yes I tested this out, unaltered after moving it and the chart works great.

My question comes in where I try to reference the `myData` computed property from within the `series` computed property. No matter how I) try it (`this.myData`, `this.myData()`, `myData`, `myData()`), it always comes back as undefined.

I find this very unusual because in the previous computed property, `myTime`, I reference `this.myData.doc[].xxx` without an issue.

Yes this probably belongs in the `this.$store.getters` section but I'd like to know why there is the difference in calling `this.myData` between the `myTime` and `series` computed properties.

The `myData` property resembles this:

```
{
  id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  doc: [
    {co2: 1800, tmp: 20, hum: 50},
    {co2: 1800, tmp: 20, hum: 50},
    {co2: 1800, tmp: 20, hum: 50},
    {co2: 1800, tmp: 20, hum: 50},
    {co2: 1800, tmp: 20, hum: 50},
    {co2: 1800, tmp: 20, hum: 50},
  ]
}
```

So the way it should work is to iterate down the `doc` array from within `myData`, pull out the co2 value, and push it to the appropriate `series[i].data` array where the chart will recognize it.

Thanks for all constructive input!

Comment: Have you checked "this" object in the "series" computed? Also, have you tried to check this.$store.state.graphData there - may be, for some reason, it doesn't exist?

Comment: `this.myData.doc[9].time`. But in `myData` sample, I saw there is no `time` property in `myData.doc`

Comment: It does have time in actuality. I just excluded for speed sake, cause the graph is intending to plot co2, hum, and tmp. Time is not needed on the x-axis as I will only be listed 10-0. myData.doc[].time is used else where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reference this before the loop

```
` let self=this; 
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    series[2].data.push(((self.myData.doc[i].co2*10)*100)/3000);
  }`
```

Comment: No way! It works! WHY!? That seems so silly.  This has to be a bug with Vue. Why would this be intentional?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I figured it out. I don't really know why Abdelhak's answer worked, but I found out what was really causing the problem.

myData is defined after an http request, fetching the data from mongo, returns that data. So what was happening, even though the request was fulfilled milliseconds after, at the time I was trying to use that data, it just wasn't there.

I fixed it by adding to divs within the template like this:

```
<template lang="html">
    <div v-if="myData">Do everything I want</div>
    <div v-else>Loading Data</div>
</template>
```

Pretty simple... Sorry to bother you all over it XD